# Filter rows of a dataframe with an equal column value

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

Let's suppose we have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c("aa", "aa", "b", "cc", "cc"), V2=c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no"))

> df
     six  seven
1    aa    yes
2    aa    yes
3     b    no
4    cc    yes
5    cc    no
```

I want to filter and, then, store in a new dataframe rows that matches 2 cryteria: same "six" column value and a specific "seven" column value. For example, let's suppose we want rows with "yes" column:

```
> df
         six seven
    1    aa   yes
    2    aa   yes
```

How can I do this? I've tried with:

```
df_new <- filter(df, ...)
```

But I'm sure sure how to impose both the conditions.

and:

```
require(plyr)
ans = ddply(df, .(seven == "yes"), mutate, count = length(unique(six)))
```

Who gives:

```
> ans
  seven == "yes" six seven count
1          FALSE   b    no     2
2          FALSE  cc    no     2
3          FALSE  cc    no     2
4           TRUE  aa   yes     1
5           TRUE  aa   yes     1
```

But this doesn't filter the dataframe.

EDIT: To clarify, if I have more columns in the dataframe, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c("aa", "aa", "b", "cc", "cc","aa","aa"), v2=c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no","no","yes"))

> df
  v1  v2
1 aa yes
2 aa yes
3  b  no
4 cc yes
5 cc  no
6 aa  no
7 aa yes
```

The code has to give this:

```
df
              six seven
        1    aa   yes
        2    aa   yes
        7    aa   yes
```

Comment: try `library(tidyverse);data.frame(V1=c("aa", "aa", "b", "cc", "cc"), V2=c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no")) %>% filter(V1=="aa", V2=="yes")`

Comment: `df[df[,'six'] == "aa" & df[,'seven'] == "yes", ]` would this suffice?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a more general code for the first condition, because my dataframe is composed of ~500 rows.

Comment: What happens if 6th row is "aa", "no" ?

Comment: @zx8754 code has to filter it (in the meaning of NOT saving it) because it doesn't match the second condition of "yes"

Comment: If the 6th row is "aa" "yes", would you return 3 rows?

Comment: @zx8754 exactly.

Comment: Then why wouldn't solution above do not apply to yours?

Comment: To clarify, what happens if 6th row is "aa", "no" ? The output will be empty?

Comment: @zx8754 The solution above works, but I need something that automatically recognize rows with the same "six" columns.  For example, if there is one more row "cc", with  "yes" value, the code have to store it along with the four row.  About your final answer, yes, the code doesn't have to store it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I had it. I leave here the solution for those who want to know:

```
types <- unique(df$six)

tmp = list()
require(dplyr)
for (k in 1:length(types)) {
  tmp[[k]] <- df %>% filter(six == types[k] & seven == "yes")
}
ls <- Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 1, tmp)
```

A bit tricky, maybe, but works. Of course, you have to extract a dataframe from the list in the end. If someone have a better idea, post it. If you're wondering why I'm using list, working with only dataframes gave me some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea via d`dplyr`. First group by `v1` and add the 2 criteria in `filter`. The group needs to be larger than 2 so to infer that `v1` values are the same, and of course `v2 == 'yes'` is self explanatory,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(v1) %>% 
 filter(n() >= 2 & all(v2 == 'yes'))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
> # Groups:   v1 [1]
>   v1    v2   
>   <fct> <fct>
> 1 aa    yes  
> 2 aa    yes
> ```

Comment: I'm trying this, but apparently, if I have another more row with "aa" and "no", it gives me an error.

Comment: Can you share the error message? It shouldn't give you error. It should simply not select that group

Comment: # A tibble: 0 x 2
# Groups:   v1 [0]
# ... with 2 variables: v1 <fct>, v2 <fct>

Comment: That is not an error. It means you don't have any groups that satisfy your criteria